# Add PDAnnotationLink to a PDF With pdfbox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I want to add a PDAnnotationLink with an action to a pdf.

I write this code

```
            ...
            PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream (doc, page,true,true);
          
            final PDAnnotationLink txtLink = new PDAnnotationLink ();

            // border style
            final PDBorderStyleDictionary linkBorder = new PDBorderStyleDictionary ();
            linkBorder.setStyle (PDBorderStyleDictionary.STYLE_UNDERLINE);
            linkBorder.setWidth (10);
            txtLink.setBorderStyle (linkBorder);
            
            // Destination URI
            final PDActionURI action = new PDActionURI ();
            action.setURI ("https://www.test.com");
            txtLink.setAction (action); 

            // Position
            final PDRectangle position = new PDRectangle (200,302,100,11);
            txtLink.setRectangle (position);
            page.getAnnotations ().add (txtLink);

            // Main page content
            contentStream.beginText ();
            contentStream.newLineAtOffset (102, 302);
            contentStream.setFont (PDType1Font.COURIER_BOLD, 10);
            contentStream.showText ("This is linked to the outside world");
            contentStream.endText ();
            contentStream.close();
```

PDAnnotationLink is added with a black rectangle over the text "This is linked to the outside world".

How can i make this rectangle trasparent?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

call

```
txtLink.setConstantOpacity(ca);
```

ca is a float value between 0 and 1. 0 is fully transparent (invisible), 1 fully visible (opaque), all between is transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually explicitly draws that *black rectangle*!

It requests an underline with a line width of 10:

```
linkBorder.setStyle (PDBorderStyleDictionary.STYLE_UNDERLINE);
linkBorder.setWidth (10);
txtLink.setBorderStyle (linkBorder);
```

As the underlying text has a font size of also 10, you can expect it to be half covered by that thick underline.

Thus, if you actually don't want that black rectangle, don't draw such a thick underline. You may want to try values of 1 or 2 there...